# Performing Raw SQL Queries with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I'm looking for create some `SQL queries` with Django but I don't have a display result.
This queries are very important because I would like to configure a research bar used by client.

**For example :**

A user wants to search all people in my table which are named 'Dupont' and living in New-York

In my `views.py`, I have written something like that :

```
def Test(request) :

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM BirthCertificate_people WHERE `name` = "Dupont" AND `city` = "New-York"''')
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    print row

    template = loader.get_template('test.html') 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

In my template file `test.html` :

```
<h2 align="center"> SQL Queries display </align> </h2>

{% block content %}

<!-- What I write there --> {{ }}

{% endblock %}
```

I don't know How I can display the SQL queries results in my .html file.

I read some tutorials : [Django Raw SQL Query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) but none results for the moment ..

Thank you so much !

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking at all. Firstly, that is a simple query that is trivial to express in the ORM; and secondly you show the data just like you would show *any other* data in Django, by passing it to the template context.

Comment: I used ORM Queries and it works. As it was the first time, I did not this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the row as a context so that it can be accessed in the html. One way to do this is by 
1) Inside your views.py import render

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

2) Now pass the template and context together

```
def Test(request) :

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM BirthCertificate_people WHERE `name` = "Dupont" AND `city` = "New-York"''')
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    print row

    context = {"row":row}
    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

3) Now inside your template "test.html" you can access your row:-

```
<h2 align="center"> SQL Queries display </align> </h2>

{% block content %}

{{ row }}

{% endblock %}
```